# Is there a way to connect an external display to a Nintendo DS/DSi/DSXL?

Tags: nintendo-ds

Are there any hardware add-ons that allow support for an external display such as a monitor or TV

Answer (score 6):

There is one non-hack way you can, but chances are you won't be able to get your hands on the hardware to do so. The **IS-NITRO-CAPTURE** is a Nintendo product that allows you to connect your DS or GBA to it, and has AV Out ports and a USB out port. This is the device that Nintendo uses at events such as E3 to show DS gameplay on a big TV. Here is a [video review](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nL9n3Mf7Mok) of the product. Unfortunately, this device costs about $3000 dollars, and it not available for consumers to buy.

If you have a friend who works at Nintendo though...

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there's no simple way to attach an external monitor to any kind of DS - it doesn't have a video output connector anywhere on it.

It's possible, though, if you're willing to [hack it to pieces and build your own breakout device](http://home.comcast.net/~olimar/DS/jumbotron/).